# 500 error on one page in entire site only showing error "You are here" instead of administration content

Tags: 7, http-request

this error seems to only affect one page in on the website, and nowhere else.
Here is what it looks like:[image]

The watchdog reports do not show the issue, and I believe it to be a permission error or caching error with Apache2, but unsure. I have tried:
clearing cache, searching for a relevant php file with unreadable permissions, and looking over .htaccess files for anything out of the ordinary.
I may have missed a few php files but I am looking for confirmation that I am heading in the right direction.

I will probably end up asking the web platform IT people for help if I can't find an answer, but anything at all will be greatly helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access to your server, you could check the actual php error logs on the server- which should indicate the exact culprit.

If you recently updated Drupal core or some contrib modules, you may want to make sure the update process completed successfully.

Also, if you were editing/adding a custom feature module, content types, field collections, paragraph bundles, or other entities referenced by the specific "People" content type, you may have accidentally removed a required field that could cause the page to break- in which case, restoring a backup database could fix the issue.